# Keeping original input in consideration for final product

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I am attempting to take two inputs, a and b, and perform an operation. My code is as follows:

```
a = int(input("Enter an integer A to be multiplied: "))
b = int(input("Enter an integer B to be multiplied: "))
x = 0

while True:
    print(a, b)
    b //= 2
    a *= 2
    if b < 1:
        break
    if b % 2 == 1:
        new = [a]
        for i in new:
            x += i
print(x)
```

If I enter 34 and 19, the output is:

```
Enter an integer A to be multiplied: 34
Enter an integer B to be multiplied: 19
34 19
68 9
136 4
272 2
544 1
612
```

The answer should be 646, as the remainder of 19%2 is 1. **Why does my code not consider 34, 19 while going through the second if statement?**

Comment: You are dividing your numbers before checking the if statement on the first iteration. You need to check the condition before doing anything to a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing your variables before the check, thus, you are checking on `b//2` and `a*2`.

Either you can assign them to temporary variable or change your code a bit:

```py
a = int(input("Enter an integer A to be multiplied: "))
b = int(input("Enter an integer B to be multiplied: "))
x = 0

while True:
    print(a, b)
    if b % 2 == 1:
        new = [a]
        for i in new:
            x += i
    b //= 2
    a *= 2
    if b < 1:
        break

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code not consider 34, 19 because you are not saving them in your list 'new'. First you are doing opetarions // and * what means your first element in list 'new' is first result of operation

```
a = int(input("Enter an integer A to be multiplied: "))
b = int(input("Enter an integer B to be multiplied: "))
x = 0

while True:
    print(a, b)
    if b < 1:
        break
    if b % 2 == 1:
        new = [a]
        for i in new:
            x += i
    b //= 2
    a *= 2
print(x)
```